# How to make hidden files not show up on Windows 7?

Tags: windows

Some time ago I made hidden files show up, and now I forgot how to make them not show up. How do I make hidden files not show up on the desktop or during file system browsing?

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Wouldn't it just be the reverse of this question http://superuser.com/questions/101999/how-do-you-show-hidden-system-folders-in-windows-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Folder Options -> View -> Select 'Don't show hidden files, folder, or drives' under 'Hidden Files and Folders'

Answer (score 2):

Orgainise menu (in any open window) > folder and search options > view > hide folders

Answer (score 1):

You open up the Folder Options dialog box (open the Start menu, type "Folder options" without quotes, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Then, under the **View** tab, in the list of options, you'll find a radio button next to "Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives". Select that, and click OK.